# What does this error mean: HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT?

Tags: http, tcp

I was receiving `HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT` when making HTTP requests with NodeJS the other day. They mysteriously stopped occurring recently, but I'm still baffled and curious what exactly `HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT` is trying to tell me.

My google search results are a bit slanted towards NodeJS, so I'm not picking up anything that describes more generally what this means. It looks like a system level error since it's all caps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think this answer is lated, but it can help some people.

I also had this problem and realized NodeJS doesn't support HTTP 0.9, that server's response contains no headers. In fact, in NodeJS documentation shows support to 1.0 and 1.1 http requests.

You can read a little more [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8514) in this issue.

Comment: In my case, I have not returned anything at all, to NodeJS client.

Answer (score 9):

The `HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT` means `Http Parse Error` and the invalid constant means that the response is malformed. So the parser can't parse it!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue when used not decoded params in request URL.

Example:

1. Request to `http://someaddress.com?query=something with whitespaces` will cause an error

   ```
     Error: Parse Error
     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
   bytesParsed: 0,
   code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT',
   ```
2. Request to `http://someaddress.com?query=something%20encoded%20with%20whitespaces` will work fine

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue because I was trying to compress files that were too small. In my specific case, I was creating a readstream of a file that was 83 bytes, and then piping it into a gzip, before finally piping it into the response

```
fs.createReadStream(file_path).pipe(gzip.createGzip()).pipe(res);
```

On the requester side, I was then trying to unzip the file

```
stream = request({"url": "https://example.com/getFile", "timeout": 200000});

//This is where the error was getting thrown
stream.pipe(gzip.createGunzip())
```

It seems that trying to compress and then decompress a file with a size somewhere less than 200 bytes will totally break this, so that was a gotcha I encountered. I guess the moral of my story is **don't compress files that are super tiny!**