# error using nodejs to do http post request

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have followed some instructions to do http request in nodejs and I am doing it in TypeScript in the following way:

code that calls the function to do http post call:

```
const getCaseInfoRequest: GetCaseInfoRequest = {
            emailAddress: 'some-email-address@amazon.com'
        };

        makeCardinalCall('/SalesforceCaseService/1.0/GetCaseInfoFromEmail', getCaseInfoRequest, process.env.STAGE)
            .then((data) => {
                ...
            }).catch(...);
```

the function that does http post call:

```
export function makeCardinalCall(path: string, requestBody: GetCaseInfoRequest, stage?: string) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const data = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

      const options: http.RequestOptions = {
         host: 'my-service.google.com',
         port: 443,
         path: path,
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': data.length,

         }
      };

      const req = http.request(options, (res: http.IncomingMessage) => {
         res.setEncoding("utf8");
         
         let data = '';
         res.on('data', chunk => {
            data += chunk;
         });
         res.on('end', () => {
            resolve(data);
         })
      });

      req.on('error', (e: any) => {
         reject(e);
      });

      req.end(data);
   });
}
```

but i always got the following error:

```
{"bytesParsed":0,"code":"HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT","reason":"Expected HTTP/","rawPacket":{"type":"Buffer","data":[21,0,0,0,2,1,0]}}
```

any hint / help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769824/what-does-this-error-mean-hpe-invalid-constant etc. What is the actual data coming back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to use the raw `http` module with an HTTPS endpoint (as evident from the port 443). The HTTP parser fails to parse the TLS bytes coming over the wire.

For your own sanity's sake, use a wrapper module for requests -- such as [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)...