# Piping Firebase stream to Express response result in HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-storage, video-streaming

I am trying to stream a video (mp4) from firebase storage to `<video>` on client. What I'm doing is using  [`createReadStream`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createReadStream) and piping it to Express response object. However on the client this error is thrown:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /movie/600d31f192e0941f9c4b4773/stream from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
> [1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT).

```
const streamMovie = async (req, res) => {
    const range = req.headers.range

    const movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id)
    const bucket = firebase.storage().bucket()

    // Get video size
    const videoFile = bucket.file(movie.videoFileUrl)
    const [metadata] = await videoFile.getMetadata()
    const videoSize = metadata.size

    // Parse range
    const parts = range.replace('bytes=', '').split('-')
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
    const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : videoSize - 1

    res.writeHead(206, {
        'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
        'Content-Length': `${end - start + 1}`,
        'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
    })

    videoFile.createReadStream({ start, end }).pipe(res)
}
```

I could not pinpoint the source of the error since I'm pretty inexperienced with streams. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream a video file to the express response object, you can use the code example from the client library [official docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createReadStream-examples). I have tested the following sample successfully:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucket = storage.bucket('bucket123');
  const remoteFile = bucket.file('videotest123.mp4');

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    'Content-Range': 'bytes=0-',
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  })

  remoteFile.createReadStream()
  .on('error', function(err) {
    res.send('there was an error');
  })
  .on('response', function(response) {})
  .on('end', function() {})
  .pipe(res);  
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

If you want to request only certain parts of the video (aka Google Cloud Storage object), you can specify within the `createReadStream` method the `start` and `end` options.

```
const remoteFile = bucket.file('videotest123');
logFile.createReadStream({
    start: 10000,
    end: 20000
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {})
  .pipe(res);
```

In regards to the `HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT` message, I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769824/what-does-this-error-mean-hpe-invalid-constant) that the message indicates an web server response malformed. In this case the `res`object from the code.

I hope you find this useful