# Istio fails with wss websockets - http-parser - HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, websocket, istio

After upgrading from 1.7.3 to 1.10.2, our springboot applications using wss fail.

Using wscat to test it, we see 502/503 errors instead of the 101 responses we expect to see with no errors. The command used to test is as follows:

```sh
wscat -c "wss://cluster-name.internal.domain.etc/inbox/application-name/rsocket" -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket"
```

Enabling debug for istio shows this:

```
application-name-64d8d8d787-29m5x istio-proxy {"level":"debug","time":"2021-08-10T12:30:16.954905Z","scope":"envoy client","msg":"[C4438] Error dispatching received data: http/1.1 protocol error: HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT"}
```

This HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT seems to come this [github project](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser/) which maps to this technical debt of istio [here](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/5155).

We tried changing port names to match "tcp" or "http" or "https" or "http2" and although response codes change, things still don't work.

Any suggestions/idea on what could we do to make this work?

Comment: "After upgrading from 1.7.3 to 1.10.2". What did you upgrade from 1.7.3 version to 1.10.2? And how? Please attach this info to the question.

Comment: Upgrade was done following this guide https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/upgrade/canary/
To the question of "what" was upgraded, control plane and sidecars were upgraded. Old istio control plane exists in the cluster and configuring the pods to use the old version, restores functionality. It only fails with new version.

Comment: Did you use Node.js server? How did you set up your http server? Did you see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769824/what-does-this-error-mean-hpe-invalid-constant)?